# How to show that $S^{\bot}$ is a linear subspace of $V$?

Tags: vector-spaces

Let $V$ be an Euclidean vector space with scalar product $(.|.)$. If $S ⊂ V$ is any subset of $V$ , define the orthogonal complement of $S$ by
$$S^{\bot}=\left\{v\in V| \forall s\in S:\left(s|v\right)=0\right\}$$

I need to show that $S^{\bot}$ is a linear subspace of $V$.

Comment: How do you normally prove that a set is a linear subspace?

Comment: Well... The subspace must have the zero vector, right?

Comment: True. But somewhere in your notes, you have written: $S\subset V$ is a subspace of $V$ if... And then you have some conditions written down.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HINT: $\forall x, y \in S^{\bot}, \forall a,b \in \mathbb{R}, \forall s \in S$ 
$$(ax+by|s) = a(x|s) + b(y|s) = a\cdot 0 + b \cdot 0 = 0$$

Comment: Sorry, but it's not enough for me. Can you hint me more?

Comment: This means that $\forall x,y \in S^{\bot}, \forall a,b \in \mathbb{R}, ax+by \in S^{\bot}$, i.e. $S^{\bot}$ is a linear subspace. What is not clear to you?

Comment: I didn't understand what you meant by using the following notation: $(ax+by|s)$ Now it's clear or it only seems clear to me...